# How do I improve my parsing technique?

Tags: python, regex, programming-languages, parser-generator

I am writing a pythonic parser for a custom language and as of now I have something like this:

```
re1 = re.compile(r"...")
re2 = re.compile(r"...")
re3 = re.compile(r"...")
re4 = re.compile(r"...")
...
...
```

Now I am reading the input file and for each line if I find a specific keyword then I am using a particular regular expression. Obviously, this is making my life a living hell because I am doing something like this:

```
if line.find("keyword1") >= 0
  # Uses re1 to match the string
  invoke_handler1() 
elif line.find('keyword2") >= 0
  # Uses re2 to match the string
  invoke_handler2() 
...
```

At the same time, I do not want to match a given line with all possible regular expressions because that would be a waste. Without discarding everything that I wrote up until this point, is there an elegant way of solving this problem and make it more efficient and readable?

Comment: Have you considered using a real [parser](http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing)?

Comment: What is this parser for? Can you elaborate on the complexity of the text/code you're parsing?

Comment: @nmichaels: I guess I need to look more into that. Thanks! @Nicolas Buduroi: I am parsing a byte-code disassembly.

Comment: Regular expressions can't count, and they can't parse nested constructions like `x = (a + (a+b)*c)*d`. You might want to read a little about language theory, and where regular languages rank in the general scheme of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than rolling your own parser using you could have a look at one of the [many parser libraries](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html) available for Python.

- [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/)
- [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/)
- [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)
- etc...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is the answer you're looking for, but I think you'd be having a better time using an actual Lexer and Tokenizer for parsing your language. I suggest looking at and learning to use [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) for this kind of task.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create a data structure the maps keywords to REs.  But honestly, I would try making REs that fail fast as a first priority and just loop over them all.

An example of a fail fast RE would be one that starts with "^Sometext" as if the first character doesn't match "S" then the rest of the RE is not evaluated.